# Initially Uncheck the payment methods in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to uncheck all the payment methods available in my woocommerce store, remember I don't to remove or disable any of payment methods.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this by editing checkout.min.js of woocommerce plugin `e.eq(0).prop("checked",!0)` to `e.eq(0).prop("checked",0)`

If anyone has better option please let me know.